# nginx subdomain ssl redirect redirects top level domain

Tags: nginx

I setup a redirect for all HTTP traffic on my subdomain to go through HTTPS but I noticed that when I visit `http://mydomain.com` it is redirecting to `https://subdomain.mydomain.com`. No problem is encountered on `https://mydomain.com`.

Just to clarify,

`http://mydomain.com` should not redirect but it currectly redirects to `https://subdomain.mydomain.com`

`http://subdomain.mydomain.com` should redirect to `https://subdomain.mydomain.com`.

This is my nginx conf

```
server {
    listen *:80;
    server_name subdomain.mydomain.com;
    server_tokens off;
    root /nowhere; # this doesn't have to be a valid path since we are redirecting, you don't have to change it.
    rewrite ^ https://$server_name$request_uri permanent;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name subdomain.mydomain.com;
    server_tokens off;
    .... other stuff ...
}
```

Comment: Where is the server block for `mydomain.com`?

Comment: It doesn't exist because mydomain is supposed to go no where until I figure what I want to put there.

Comment: If it doesn't exist, then the first server block that is available is used, thus it redirects. You must setup a server block for `mydomain.com` that prints a default message or something.

Comment: Foibs, thank you so much. That clarifies everything. Feel free to add an answer and I'll mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting from http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html

> nginx first decides which server should process the request. Let’s
>   start with a simple configuration where all three virtual servers
>   listen on port *:80:

```
server {
    listen      80;
    server_name example.org www.example.org;
    ...
}

server {
    listen      80;
    server_name example.net www.example.net;
    ...
}

server {
    listen      80;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    ...
}
```

> In this configuration nginx tests only the request’s header field
>   “Host” to determine which server the request should be routed to. If
>   its value does not match any server name, or the request does not
>   contain this header field at all, then nginx will route the request to
>   the default server for this port. In the configuration above, the
>   default server is the first one — which is nginx’s standard default
>   behaviour.

That means that in your example, when you make a request to `http://mydomain.com` the only available server block to serve the request is the `server_name subdomain.mydomain.com;` block, so it redirects to https. The simplest solution is to create a new server block called which just returns a http status code and possibly a message. E.g.

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name mydomain.com;
  return 403 "nothing to see here";
}
```

You may also use `default_server` like this `listen 80 default_server;` to make sure that all 'unconfigured' hostnames will come in this block

Comment: i setup a temporary place holder page and it worked perfectly. thanks!